# Creating the load_summarize_chain for Langchain,specified chain_type=map_reduce. get an error when using the prompts

Tags: python, openai-api, chatgpt-api, langchain

I'm trying to create the load_summarize_chain for Langchain using prompts that I created myself.

```
llm = ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0.7)
PROMPT = PromptTemplate(template=prompt_template, input_variables=["text"])
chain = load_summarize_chain(llm, chain_type="refine", verbose=True, prompt=PROMPT)
```

However, I'm only able to successfully create the chain when the chain_type is set as "stuff". When I try to specify it as "map_reduce" or "refine", I get an error message like the following:

```
ValidationError: 1 validation error for RefineDocumentsChain
prompt
  extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
```

What's wrong with it？

I think it might be because "map_reduce" or "refine" cannot directly specify custom prompts in the `load_summarize_chain`, or some other reason.

Comment: Change `prompt=PROMPT` to `refine_prompt=PROMPT`. See this [example](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/chains/index_examples/summarize.html#:~:text=refine_prompt%3Drefine_prompt)

Answer (score 8):

When your `chain_type='map_reduce'`, The parameter that you should be passing is `map_prompt` and `combine_prompt` where your final code will look  like

```
chain = load_summarize_chain(llm, chain_type="map_reduce",verbose=True,map_prompt=PROMPT,combine_prompt=COMBINE_PROMPT)
```

where PROMPT and COMBINE_PROMPT are custom prompts generated using `PromptTemplate`

AND
When your `chain_type='refine'`, the parameter that you should be passing is `refine_prompt` and your final block of code looks like

```
chain = load_summarize_chain(llm, chain_type="refine",verbose=True,refine_prompt=PROMPT)
```